# JAVA using Printable print method

Tags: java

I found a usefull code but i don't understand two things from it. The first one is with `if (page > 0)` . What does that mean ? And also here where it should print `job.print();` . Why is it calling this method without any parameter and not this one i created earlier ? :  `public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int page)`

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.print.*;

public class HelloWorldPrinter implements Printable, ActionListener {


    public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int page) throws
                                                        PrinterException {

        if (page > 0) {   //Here
            return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
        }



//this one
        System.out.println(pf.getWidth());

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2d.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY());


        g.drawString("Hello world!", 100, 100);


        return PAGE_EXISTS;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
         job.setPrintable(this);
         boolean ok = job.printDialog();
         if (ok) {
             try {
                  job.print();  //Here
             } catch (PrinterException ex) {

             }
         }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE);
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Hello World Printer");
        f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
           public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {System.exit(0);}
        });
        JButton printButton = new JButton("Print Hello World");
        printButton.addActionListener(new HelloWorldPrinter());
        f.add("Center", printButton);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The first one is with if (page > 0) . What does that mean ?

Printing can consist of multiple pages - the `PrinterJob` does not know how many pages to print, so it will call the `print` method of your `Printable` implementation until it is told to do so (eg `NO_SUCH_PAGE` is returned). One of the parameters passed to your implementation of the `print` (eg `page`) is incremented for every page, and indicates the current page number being printed. As a result, this conditional limits the printing to a single page.

> And also here where it should print job.print(); . Why is it calling this method without any parameter and not this one i created earlier ?

You first call `print` on the `PrinterJob`, `PrinterJob` then creates the variables which are then passed to your `print` implementation (sometimes multiple times, depending upon the number of pages) - so you are indirectly calling your `Printable` implementation (eg the 3 parameter `print` method).

Oracle has a great [printing tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/) worth reading in depth that might further answer questions you have.

Comment: Do you know why the my print implementation is called 2 times ?

Comment: `PrinterJob` will keep calling until `NO_SUCH_PAGE` is returned. The first call (eg the first page) returns  `PAGE_EXISTS`, so `PrinterJob` calls the method a second time and in this context,  `NO_SUCH_PAGE` is returned (hence, two calls to the `Printable` implementation)

Comment: So even if NO_SUCH_PAGE is returned, any code after this is still called ? ( if (page > 0) {
            return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
        }
        
        System.out.println(pf.getWidth());    )

Comment: No, the method [returns](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html)

Comment: It prints the width two times

Comment: What `width`? Do you mean it prints two pages?

Comment: No. It prints one page . Check my edited post. The line with the system.out is called twice.

Comment: See the API for [Printable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/print/Printable.html) - to quote: `The printing system may request a page index more than once`. This doesn't mean it will print the same page twice, but it may *request* ( from `Printable` (eg call the `print` implementation) more than once.

Answer (score 0):

Q1: `if (page > 0)` . What does that mean ? - This makes sure only the first page is printed. Because you are using a `Printable`, rather than a `Pageable`, it doesn't know how many pages there are to print.

Q2: And also here where it should print job.print(); - It should call job.print where you want to send the print job to the printer. In your case, on the button click

Q3: Why is it calling this method without any parameter and not this one i created earlier ? - These are two different classes and objects. You are calling print() on a `PrinterJob`, which, calls back your `Printable` print method to print the page. On the line: `job.setPrintable(this);` that's how it knows to call back the print method you specified

Comment: Do you happen to know why is my print implementation called two times ?

Comment: It is called once for page 1, and once for page 2. When handling the second page, you are returning NO_SUCH_PAGE so it doesn't ask for any more pages